# pandas: split values and join across columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv of some user data, that for whatever reason or other has separated the email name and the email domain into two separate columns. Some users also have multiple emails. I would like to join these into a single email or single list, as the case permits.

example:

```
emailname                          | emaildomain
john.smith; smithj                 | gmail.com, biz.net
sample.name                        | aol.com
```

I would like to change that to:

```
email
[john.smith@gmail.com, smithj@biz.net]
[sample.name@aol.com]
```

from there, it will be pushed to a dictionary, where I will have to iterate over each value in the cell and make an entry from those, which I have a rough idea how to do just using basic python, or by following similar logic.

I was able to split each field to a list using `df['email name'] = df['email name'].str.split(';')` which gave me a list for each value in the field. However, I am stuck at how I would join them into a single field.

In pure python I would do something like:

```
emaillist = []
for i in emailname: #where the assumption is there is a 1:1 relationship between each name and domain
    e = '@'.join(emailname[i],emaildomain[i])
    emaillist.append(e)
```

but in pandas, i am unsure of how to take an index of a list inside a cell of a dataframe. Ideally, I would also like to skip any blank rows, but if just creates an "empty" list like: `[@]` then it's fine, I can fix that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try this. It will create a new column email of your desired output

```py
final_email = []
for i,k in enumerate(zip(list(df['Emailname'].values), list(df['Emaildomain'].values))):
  name,domain = k
  a = []
  for ij, val in enumerate(name.split(';')):
    val = val+'@'+str(domain.split(',')[ij]).strip()
    a.append(val)
  final_email.append(a)
df['Email'] = final_email
df
```

Comment: I keep getting a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: Are you applying this to your whole dataset?

Comment: just these two columns, but all the way down, yes.

Comment: your whole values of emalname and emaildomain should be in same form as you have given in the question otherwise it might show error. Just imagine your data like this `john.smith, smithj` instead of `john.smith; smithj`.  Change from `;`  to ','  can show error. It depends on your dataset

Comment: Ok then can you find what row is it causing the error? You can split the dataframe to many small dataframes and check the above code in those dataframes until you get the small dataframe which is causing the error.

Comment: I found it. It was one entry where it had one less domain, than email name. Fixed that and this solution worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use nested list comprehension with `*` for unpack lists:

```
L = [['@'.join(z) for z in zip(*[y.split(',') for y in x])] 
                  for x in zip(df['emailname'],df['emaildomain'])]
print (L)
[['john.smith@gmail.com', 'smithj@biz.net'], ['sample.name@aol.com']]
```

Comment: Hmm. So I tried this and I get `AttributeError: 'list object has no attribute 'split'`. I re-did it without already splitting the multiple-value cells, and it joined them incorrectly, `['john.smith;smithj@gmail.com;biz.net]'`. I tried moving the `.split(';')` to the 2nd line of the comprehension, and it also gives an error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: @noscodemos - Is possible some misisng values? If use `df = df.dropna()` before my solution it working?

Comment: There are some blank values, but in theory that should just create a list with value `[@]`. Doing a `dropna()` had no effect.

Comment: @noscodemos One idea 0 can you test `L = [['@'.join(z) for z in zip(*[y.split(',') for y in x])] 
                  for x in zip(df['emailname'].astype(str),df['emaildomain'].astype(str))]` ?